# Bootstrap Carousel Not Working

Tags: jquery, html, carousel

I'm struggling with Bootstrap carousel on my site. I've followed the instructions and looked for answers here and I'm still stuck, seems like everything I've done is ok..yet it clearly isn't! My carousel is not working. 
Why isn't it working?

I've been sitting on this so long and getting nowhere so I will really appreciate your help guys.

Many thanks!

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>Hello World!</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Catamaran:300,400,100' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<script src="js/bootstrap-carousel.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myCarousel').carousel({
    //options here
    });
});

</script> 
    <!-- Custom styles for this template go here -->

    <!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy this line! -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../docs-assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="nav">

            <div class="logoimg">

                <img src="img/logo3.png">


            </div>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="about.html">About</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="faq.html">FAQ</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>


        <!-- Carousel -->

        <div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <!-- Indicators -->
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>

            <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                <div class="item active">
                    <img src="img/slide1.jpg" alt="Slide 1">
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                    <img src="img/slide2.jpg" alt="Slide 2">
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                    <img src="img/slide3.jpg" alt="Slide 3">
                </div>
            </div>


            <!-- Controls -->
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>


        <!-- Carousel End-->


    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: Hi--please show your script references--the order of your script loading could cause it not to work.

Comment: You provided more code, but my answer still applies. You need jQuery for this to work. Please read below. You can download a local copy of jQuery if you like and upload it to your site as well, but I find using CDNs just as effective if not better.

Comment: Hi thanks a lot! I will try this now. My brain is on a learning curve here lol!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simply put, you didn't include the jQuery library. Here is the error console is showing:

`ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

9 times out of 10 this can be solved by loading jQuery in the `head` of your document. Like so:

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Catamaran:300,400,100' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<!-- This is the important part -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

In essence, vanilla javascript has NO idea what this code means, as it is specific to jQuery syntax:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myCarousel').carousel({
    //options here
    });
});
```

Therefore your carousel is never loaded or rendered and only the plain HTML is being shown.

Comment: It's working now! Thanks a lot! I've looked again at my course materials and it's all there... I've missed quite an important bit...Haha..Thanks!

Comment: If this provided a reasonable answer for your question, please select the green checkbox next to the voting arrows by my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The order is also important.
First you must include jquery and then bootstrap, otherwise it will  not work.

This is the correct order:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
```